# Using different server for running WSO2 App-manager and EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to use the coding of app-manager or EMM and run it on a different server like JBOSS. If yes than how can we implement it.Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No both are standalone products, not webapplication. But, You can run them inside a container like kubernetes.

Do you have any reason to run them inside JBOSS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just exploring the possibilities that can be implemented.

Comment: Which server does wso2 Appm and EMM uses?

Comment: Embedded tomcat for deploying apps